# Can't ping Guest on VirtualBox from Host

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I'm unable to ping my guest VM from my host.

- Host: Win7
- VirtualBox 5.2.6
- Guest:  CentOS 7

On VB I have my guest CentOS 7 network configured with 2 adapters.

- Adapter 1 Attached to NAT
- Adapter 2 Attached to Host-only Adapter (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter)

[image]

On CentOS 7

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e3:8c:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 84885sec preferred_lft 84885sec
    inet6 fe80::db4c:7b23:6a34:d832/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:0b:4f:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:99:20:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:99:20:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I think the virbr0 192.168.122.1 is weird.  I would have expected 192.168.56.XXX.

ifcfg-enp0s3

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=d36ec069-6fa5-429f-a89b-debf35c2346e
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

On my host Win 7 I ping 192.168.122.1 and get a connection timeout.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the firewall on one or both the host and guest machine. Also, switch  the guest to Bridged Adapter.

Comment: This did not work.  Guest (CentOS) iptables configured to accept anything.  I don't have permission to disable the firewall on host (Win) but I don't believe that's the issue.  Ubuntu on the same host and VirtualBox works fine.